# Complex Numbers: Areas and More

Tags: complex-numbers

How Do I Do these Problems!?

1. What is the area of the region of the complex plane defined by $|z|<5$?
2. Find all complex numbers $z$ such that $|z-1|=|z+3|=|z-i|$.

Express each answer in the form $a+bi$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

For 1) ,  I know that if the problem was $|z|\leq5$, then it would just be a circle with radius $5$, hence $25\pi$, but what do I subtract to make it $|z|<5?$

Comment: For 1) the area of the boundary (circumference) is zero, so $|z|<5$ it is a circle without boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Use $z=a+bi$ and then:

$1)$ $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}<5 \Rightarrow a^2+b^2<5^2$, what is a circle with radius $5$;

$2)$ $|z-1|=|z+3|=|z-i| \Leftrightarrow (a-1)^2+b^2=(a+3)^2+b^2=a^2+(b-1)^2$

$$(a-1)^2+b^2=(a+3)^2+b^2=a^2+(b-1)^2\Leftrightarrow-2a+1=6a+9=-2b+1$$
 Solve the system.